# MD81: Why are there so many lights on the fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design, fuselage, dc-9-family, aircraft-external-lights, md-80

Looking at this photo I can see lots of lights on the fuselage of this MD81. It can't be a reflection, can it?

[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Aerolineas-Argentinas-%28Austral/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-81/0390855/&sid=8e991c7a68f8c7259f16b188192a6060)

Why are there so many lights?

Comment: For what I can see, the spot of light below the windows is a reflection of the wingtip light.

Comment: Are the other lights simply interior lights visible through the windows perhaps?

Comment: Does the smoke qualify for ground-ɕheɱtrᶏil? It's a trᶏil, and it's ɕheɱical...

Comment: There are a couple of close votes on this: I'm voting to leave open as it does appear to be a fair question relating to "Are these lights part of the aircraft, or an optical illusion" which would seem to be on-topic to me?

Answer (score 6):

I think they are reflection from some light posts in the background environment (green line above the blue "horizon" light), and the reflection of the wingtip position light.

[image: Reflection Comments]

Comment: The one you circled in red is an actual light, to illuminate the wing leading edge. I think you are right about the rest though.

Comment: @fooot Interesting! Is that for in-flight inspection purposes, or?

Answer (score 5):

On the fuselage, only 3 per side (discounting the red anti-collision which is above/below):

1. Ground flood aka runway turnoff lights.
2. Leading edge for inspecting the wing and for higher visibility on ground to other vehicles.
3. Nacelle.

[image]
([airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Allegiant-Air/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-82-DC-9-82/5002123))

And here they are from an MD-80 flight manual:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd say they're reflections. You can see the reflection of a building or something like it on the fuselage, and if you look close enough, you can see the poles of the 2 first lights.
Also most of them are at or near the windows' corners. There aren't any housings or mounts to lights on those spots.